# imagick php 7.2 not setting webp format

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, webp

I have ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 and cwebp and dwebp (libwebp, libwebp-devel) installed and working as expected from the command line.

I have php7.2 installed from webtatic.

the problem I'm facing is that php imagick is not wrking with webp extension (other formats are working fine)
here's what I get when I try Imagick:
**Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: Unable to set image format in .... : Imagick->setimageformat('webp')**

please help me, I googled a lot, stackoverflow has nothing regarding this issue.. any clue, guidance, answer will be apreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Run `php -i | grep ImageMagick`. Is `WEBP` listed under "supported formats"? If not, you may need to install `Imagick` from source.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did so, it is not listed. but the thing is it works just fine from the command line **convert image.jpg image.webp** sorry if I look a bit annoying, but why doesn't it work? besides can I uninstall imagemagick 6 and install imagemagick 7 without affecting php's imagick?  (i read somewhere that I should do so)

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `Imagick->setimageformat('webp')` use the following syntax instead:

`$imagick = new \Imagick('/tmp/foo.jpg'); 
$imagick->writeImage('webp:/tmp/foo.webp');`

That should do the trick for you ;-)

Comment: i used this method and output file has webp format but it's contents is with jpeg file format